# Layout Issue on Small Screens

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm working on a Android App. Layout working fine on every device except where device screen size 480x800 & less.

How can create separate layouts by only targeting that screen size or less?

I'm already tried `layout-hdpi`, `layout-small-hdpi` & `layout-normal-hdpi` since phone like Nexus S, Nexus One are in `hdpi` category. But when I create separate layouts like `layout-hdpi` those layouts are affecting phone with bigger screen like Pixel, Pixel2, Nexus 5 etc.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Phones (as opposed to tablets) tend to come in about three size groups (as far as Android resources are concerned): those with smallest width of 320dp, those with 360dp, and those with 410dp. The resources framework gives you a way to target any device *larger* than a certain width, so the correct technique is to put layouts for *small* screens on the default folder, and layouts for larger screens in one of the qualified folders.

Since it sounds like your layouts currently work well for anything 360dp or larger, you can make two layout directories:

```
res/
    layout/
    layout-sw360dp/
```

Put the special layouts for the small screens inside `res/layout/` and put the “normal” layouts in the other directory.

Answer (score 0):

Its not easy but you can also specify layouts based on the smallest width and you you supply the numbers. You can get more detailed and separate layouts that way however in my experience you will still run into that problem from time to time. In my current project using this method I have specific folders for W360 and W400 to deal with smaller devices for one specific screen.
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is a layout bucket with the **smallest width qualifier**.
A layout with a set smallest width will be active, **unless** the smaller of the both dimensions (width or height) is lower than a certain value you can choose.

So, when a device has a smallest width below some value **X** it will use the default layout, when the value is **X** or more it will use the defined smallest width layout.

To create such a layout file in Android Studio, you wanna right-click your **layout** directory, click on **new -> Layout Resource File** and select the **Smallest Screen Width** qualifier from the list of available qualifiers. Now you need to specify your smallest width, which in your case should be slightly above 480dp. Give it the same name as your current layout file. Place your code for devices with a smallest width above 480p here. Now change the code in your other layout file, without the smallest width qualifier, to support smaller screens.

For further reference take a look at the official [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) page.